# Accessing nose verbosity programmatically

Tags: python, nose

I've got some tests which log to stdout, and I'd like to change the log level in my test script based on the verbosity that nose is running on.

How can I access the verbosity of the running nose instance, from within one of the tests being run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the expected way to handle this in nose is to use the `logger` framework within your tests, and then control the level to be captured with the `--logging-level` option.

By default nose will capture all logs made by the tests, but a filter can be specified using `--logging-filter` config parameter.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a hack, but you could figure out which nose.config.Config object the current test runner is using, and check the config.verbosity attribute.

```
import nose.config
def test_checkverbosity():
    import gc
    for obj in gc.get_objects():
        if isinstance(obj, nose.config.Config):
            break
    print obj.verbosity
    assert False
```

Comment: Thanks, will play with this and see if it does what I need. I was hoping that nose kept a reference to its instance in the module, or something along those lines.